# How to concatenate 2 dict in Python with concat

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have 2 dict objects with the same key but different elements.I would like to merge  them into one dict.

First, I used append and it works but append is deprecated so that I prefer to use concat.

here is the code :

```
data1 = {'a':1, 'b':2}
data2 = {'a':3, 'b':4}

list = [data1, data2]
df = pd.DataFrame()

for x in range(len(list)):
    df = df.append(list[x], ignore_index=True)
    
df
```

The code below works with append. In my case I would like to have concat
Maybe you can help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following code works but may not be very efficient:

```py
data1 = {'a':1, 'b':2}
data2 = {'a':3, 'b':4}

list = [data1, data2]
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(list[i], index=[i]) for i in range(len(list))])

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proposition using [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with [`pandas.DataFrame.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) :

```
list_of_dicts = [data1, data2]

df= (
        pd.concat(dict(enumerate(map(pd.Series,
                                     list_of_dicts))))
            .unstack()
    )
```

##### # Output :

```
print(df)

   a  b
0  1  2
1  3  4
```

*NB : Try to avoid naming your variables with python built-in function names (list, dict, ..)*